# WordPress: Как добавить директорию для поиска шаблонов?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как известно мы можем подключать шаблоны к созданным страницам. Мы просто в начале файла в комментариях указываем `Template name: Имя шаблона`. После кладем его в директорию например `/pages` и после в админке указываем созданный шаблон для страницы.

Моя проблема: Мои шаблоны лежат по пути `templates/pages/` и wordpress не видит мои шаблоны. Так как он не видит шаблоны которые лежат на 2м/3ем уровне директорий

Попытки решения: Я нашел вот такой способ который возвращает имена файлов, а не названия шаблонов.

```
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', function( $templates ){
    $templates_dir = 'templates/pages/';
    $templates_files = scandir(locate_template($templates_dir));

    foreach ( $templates_files as $file ) {
        if ( $file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
        $name = explode('.', $file);
        $templates[$templates_dir.$file] = $name[0];
    }
    return $templates; 
});
```

Вопрос: Как можно переделать мой код чтобы он возвращал названия шаблонов или может есть другой более удобный способ?

Answer (score 0):

[Шаблоны темы](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/) находятся в её корне. Но в них можно подключать части, находящиеся в подкаталоге с помощью [get_template_part](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_template_part)

Например

```
get_template_part( 'inc/nav' ); // подключит файл inc/nav.php
```

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли. Когда я создаю страницу я там могу выбрать для нее шаблон который сам свертсал. Но только если он не лежит в под каталоге.

Comment: @MaxWatson Всё верно, я так и написал - шаблоны берутся только из корня темы. Этого в достаточно и незачем парсить все подкаталоги. А если надо, то можно подключать (по условиям например) части шаблонов, которые уже могут быть в подкаталогах.